# Where is Kindle.exe so I can change Windows Defender Controlled Flolder Access to allow updates

Tags: kindle, windows

Now I have to turn Controlled folder access off to get updates.
It's annoying.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `kindle.exe` is installed in the following folder:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Amazon\Kindle\application`

To display it:

1. Press [image]**+R** to display the **Run** dialog box.
2. Copy and paste `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Amazon\Kindle\application`and press Enter.

Comment: Thanks Nemo XXX!!!    I was all about finding the .exe not the Kindle\APPLICATION Your kind advice worked great :)